Is the inorder predecessor of a node with no left subtree and being the left child of its parent always its grandparent?
I'm trying to understand the rules for finding the inorder predecessor of a node in a binary search tree (BST).

If a node  has a left subtree, the inorder predecessor is the
largest value in that left subtree.

If node  has no left subtree,
the predecessor is one of its ancestors. But if node  is the right child, then its parent p is its predecessor


Here’s my specific question:
If node  has no left subtree and is a left child of its parent, its parent  cannot be the predecessor because  is larger than . In this case, we move up the tree to find the ancestor that is smaller than , and that ancestor is 's predecessor.
Take a look at this BST:
         50
        /  \
      30    70
     /  \
   20   40
       /
      35


Node  = 35 has no left subtree and is the left child of its parent
40 (the parent) cannot be the inorder predecessor because it's larger
than 35.
We move up the tree to the parent of 40, which is 30.
30 is smaller than 35, so 30 is the inorder predecessor of 35.

Is it true that the inorder predecessor of node  in this situation is always its grandparent, or could it be a more distant ancestor?

Just think how the BST would look if the root node were 32

@gimix, the BST could have many forms. I'm not sure how your comment helps.

@trincot, since the tree in the example is unbalanced, it could have been created e.g. from inserting items in order [50,30,70,20,40,35]. If we insert 32 instead of 50 as root, and then exactly all the other items in exactly the same order, we have a tree where the predecessor of 35 is not its grandparent, but the root node (grand-grandparent)

The node you seek is the closest (lowest) ancestor, for whom the node in question is a right-side descendant, if such ancestor exists.
Example
In a tree like this
    4
     \
      8
     / \
    7   9
   /
  6
 /
5

the predecessor of 5 is 4, which is not its grandparent (that is 7).
It is, however, the closest ancestor of 5, for which 5 is its right-side descendant (for all closer ancestors, that is for 6, 7 and 8, the 5 is a left-side descendant).

As we know, the inorder traversal of a BST results in a sorted array in ascending order.
For my tree it is 20, 30, 35, 40, 50, 70.
Here 30 is the predecessor of 35 and is also its grandparent in the BST.
Since 35 has no left subtree and is a left child of its parent, 40, would the predecessor of such a node always be its grandparent, i.e., 30 in this example?

Nope. See the example I added to my answer.
